# What happens to incoming messages from twilio when server is down

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

When there is an incoming message to a twilio number, twilio will try to post the message to an endpoint provided in the [webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-a-webhook). But what's the expected behavior if the endpoint is not accessible or server is down? Can the message be retrieved later or is the message shown as undelivered to the person sending the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Firstly, I recommend you set up a fallback URL, so that if Twilio can't reach your primary server then it can try again to a secondary one. That fallback URL should be served by a different application than your primary URL so that if the primary is down, it doesn't affect the fallback.

If your fallback also fails, the message is not lost. You can still retrieve the contents of the messages from the API using the [Message resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message). It is also visible in the [SMS logs in your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/logs).